# Auto login FB app users into my site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas

On my website, the user can log in through Facebook.
I have also created a Facebook canvas app which consists of a small part of my website.

Through the Facebook canvas app, the user can access certain features of the site regarding their site account.

It works great when the user accesses the FB app while already being logged into the site.
However, if the user accesses the FB app while NOT being logged into my site - how do I log them into my site through the app?

It would be ideal if I could somehow automatically log them into their account when accessing my site through the FB app.

If that isn't possible, I would like the user to be able to log into my site through the Facebook app.
However right now when I redirect to the oauth login I get the following error:

> Refused to display
>   'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=…nLpHx7N5X--Q'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Summary:

1. **Can I auto-login to my site when accessing the site through Facebook canvas**
2. **If not, how can the user log into my site through the canvas app?**

Comment: So you effectively have two logins, one for your site, and one for the Facebook app? How are the accounts connected? Are you using any kind of framework for your site and its login system? (Those usually provide methods to perform a login action via code.)

Comment: @CBroe
I'm using ASP.NET MVC.

The accounts are connected through Oauth, eg. the user can sign up to my site using Facebook oauth.

Comment: @CBroe
And the user is supposed to use the same login for both the app and the site. 
The scenario I'm describing is where is where the user is accessing my FB app (while obviously being logged into FB) but not being logged into my site.

Comment: So basically your problem is just how to call the FB login dialog from within canvas? If you use the URL redirect version, then you have to call it in the top window instance – the login dialog can not be shown in any kind of (i)frame, for security reasons. Or simply use the JS SDK and its `FB.login` method (that makes for a much nicer user experience on canvas anyway, because the user doesn’t have to leave the canvas, but the login dialog is shown as a modal dialog.)

Comment: @CBroe I have now successfully logged in using the JS SDK (FB.login).

However, when I refresh, my website does still redirect to the login page (meaning that apparently my site didn't recognize that the user logged in to my site).

(I am using a standard ASP.NET MVC authorize setup if you are familiar with that)

Comment: No, not familiar with that. I know that the PHP SDK and the JS SDK are able to work hand-in-hand, via the FB cookies set under the app domain; but that doesn’t necessarily mean that other server-side frameworks have implemented it the same way. As an alternative, you can continue with the server-side login flow, you just have to call the login URL in the top window instance (so `top.location.href=…` in JavaScript, or `target="_top"` for a simple link.)

Comment: @CBroe
I ended up doing just that and it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: OK, added the essential bits as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically your problem was just how to call the FB login dialog from within canvas. If you use the URL redirect version, then you have to call it in the top window instance – the login dialog can not be shown in any kind of (i)frame, for security reasons¹

`top.location.href=…` in JavaScript, or `target="_top"` for a simple link can achieve that.

---

¹ User needs to be able to verify via address bar that they are entering their credentials on facebook.com, to prevent phishing attacks.